# How I can get Second max salary using "over(partition by)" in oracle SQL?

Tags: sql, oracle, greatest-n-per-group, window-functions

I already get it by doing this query:

```
   SELECT * 
    FROM
      (
      SELECT emp_id,salary,row_number() over(order by salary  desc) AS rk 
      FROM test_qaium
      ) 
    where rk=2;
```

But one of my friend ask me to find second `MAX` salary from employees table must using "`over(partition by )`" in oracle sql. Anybody please help me.
And clear me the concept of "`Partition by`" in oracle sql.

Comment: will you please provide me a query ?

Comment: Your query seems to do what you are describing. What exactly is your problem?

Comment: Please **[EDIT]** your question and add some [sample data](http://plaintexttools.github.io/plain-text-table/) and the expected output based on that data. [**Formatted text**](http://stackoverflow.com/help/formatting) please, [**no screen shots**](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285551/why-may-i-not-upload-images-of-code-on-so-when-asking-a-question/285557#285557). **[edit]** your question - do **not** post code or additional information in comments.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**Oracle Setup**:

```
CREATE TABLE test_qaium ( emp_id, salary, department_id ) AS
  SELECT  1, 10000, 1 FROM DUAL UNION ALL
  SELECT  2, 20000, 1 FROM DUAL UNION ALL
  SELECT  3, 30000, 1 FROM DUAL UNION ALL
  SELECT  4, 40000, 1 FROM DUAL UNION ALL -- One highest, one 2nd highest
  SELECT  5, 10000, 2 FROM DUAL UNION ALL
  SELECT  6, 20000, 2 FROM DUAL UNION ALL
  SELECT  7, 30000, 2 FROM DUAL UNION ALL
  SELECT  8, 30000, 2 FROM DUAL UNION ALL -- Two highest, one 2nd highest
  SELECT  9, 10000, 3 FROM DUAL UNION ALL
  SELECT 10, 10000, 3 FROM DUAL UNION ALL -- Two highest, no 2nd highest
  SELECT 11, 10000, 4 FROM DUAL UNION ALL -- One highest, no 2nd highest
  SELECT 12, 20000, 5 FROM DUAL UNION ALL
  SELECT 13, 20000, 5 FROM DUAL UNION ALL
  SELECT 14, 30000, 5 FROM DUAL;          -- One highest, Two 2nd highest
```

**Query**:

This will get all the rows with the 2nd highest salary for each department:

```
SELECT * 
FROM   (
  SELECT t.*,
         DENSE_RANK() OVER (PARTITION BY department_id
                            ORDER BY salary DESC) AS rnk 
  FROM   test_qaium t
) 
WHERE  rnk=2;
```

**Output**:

```
EMP_ID SALARY DEPARTMENT_ID RNK
------ ------ ------------- ---
     3  30000             1   2
     6  20000             2   2
    12  20000             5   2
    13  20000             5   2
```

Comment: Thank you so much. want exactly this one. 
But sorry to say, due to my low reputation I can't vote for your answer.

Answer (score 2):

If you have multiple employees on the same salary, your query will not work...

Try:

```
SELECT emp_id,
       salary,
       dense_rank() over(order by salary desc) AS rk 
FROM test_qaium
```

The `partition by` clause works like a group by, and there's nothing here that needs grouping.

Comment: Thank you. But I mention that i must use "over(partition by )" in the query. Actually it was just for a curiosity to know is it possible.